# Bootstrap DateTimePicker set default date based on allowed Dates

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap DateTimePicker for my project and I have added the property `daysOfWeekDisabled` so that only Thursday, Friday and Saturday is allowed to be selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            inline: true,
            format: "dd MM yyyy",
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 1, 2, 3],
            minDate: Date.now()
        }).on('dp.change', function (e, selecteddate, $td) {
            $('.input-field1').val(e.date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
            $('.FormDownDateSelect').slideToggle("fast", function () { });
            CheckIfDateAndTimeIsSelected();
        })
    </script>
```

My question is how can I set the default date so if we say that today is Monday it will Set the next Thursday as Default selected date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useCurrent: false
```

**Change to:**

```
useCurrent: true
```

Because you have said that Sunday -> Wednesday is not allowed it will automaticly set the default date as the next avalible date.